# Finding solution for pancake sort efficiently without actually flipping each time

Tags: c++, sorting

## Problem

Solve correct flips to sort given input with pancake sort.

### Example

```
input (input size and values):
8
6 7 2 5 1 4 3 8

solution (number of flips and how many elements to flip per operation):
6
2 7 4 5 3 4

    2 -> 7 6 2 5 1 4 3 8 
    7 -> 3 4 1 5 2 6 7 8 
    4 -> 5 1 4 3 2 6 7 8 
    5 -> 2 3 4 1 5 6 7 8 
    3 -> 4 3 2 1 5 6 7 8 
    4 -> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 

alternative solution:
6
3 6 2 5 7 3
```

Program doesn't need to actually sort anything, just give one possible solution.

What would be faster way to calculate needed flips without resorting to sorting input with ineffective pancake sort?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    using namespace std;
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> v(N);
    vector<int> flips;

    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
        cin >> v[i];

    auto first  = v.begin();
    auto last   = v.end();
    for (; first != last; --last)
    {
        auto mid = max_element(first, last);
        if (mid == last - 1) {
            continue;
        }
        if (first != mid) {
            flips.push_back(distance(first, mid+1));
            reverse(first, mid + 1);
        }
        flips.push_back(distance(first, last));
        reverse(first, last);
    }

    cout << flips.size() << endl;
    for (auto flip : flips)
        cout << flip << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: what is mid supposed to mean?
in your code, first, last and mid are not defines

Comment: @user154327 What do you mean not defines? They are declared with automatic type deduction and used.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should drop namespace std; It is bad practice even in challenges.
2. Use more descriptive names even if the variable is named so in the problem. You can also use a range based loop for the initialization of the elements.

   ```
   size_t vectorLength;
   std::cin >> vectorLength;
   std::vector<int> numbers(vectorLength);    
   for (auto &number : numbers) {
       std::cin >> number;
   }
   ```
3. You declare the iterators outside of the loop, which is uneccessary, if both have the same type.

   ```
   for (auto first  = v.begin(), last = v.end(); first != last; --last)
   ```

   Also you iterate from the end so you might want to think about using reverse iterators aka `rbegin()` and `rend()`
4. When comparing or increasing iterators, you should use `mid == std::next(last, 1)` and or `std::prev` accordingly. This works with every kind of iterator.

This also brings me to the bad choice of your loop variable. the iterator is called last and you compare with `std::next(last, 1)`, which one would expect to be out of memory access. Instead define an explicit iterator `auto it = numbers.end()` and use it in your loop, avoiding confusion.

Comment: Any idea how to solve this without using reverse?